# Customized Audio Visualizer for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio, opengl, spotify, audio-player

I'm look for an audio visualizer for ubuntu, mainly for spotify.

The only thing I could find was Glava -
https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/11/embed-audio-visualizer-on-your-linux.html
Which is great but it needs to be configured, and I lack any creative abilities to create a something asthetic.
I was hoping someone could share their custom setup including a suitable background image.

Any alternatives would also be much appreciated. I am not necessarily looking for something embedded in the background, any external window app will also be great, as long as it supports spotify and looks good.

Not sure if this is an appropriate forum for this question. If not kindly suggest an alternative.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [Cavalier](https://www.omglinux.com/cavalier-music-visualizer-app-for-linux/) which is pretty cool I would say. I use this image as the background.

[image: I use this image as the background.]

As far as personalization,
drawing mode:bars
under the 'CAVA' menu,
no.of bars-72
in the colors menu, I just select 5 colors starting from the bottom of the image to the top of the image.

Here they are (from bottom to top).

1.#271B29
2.#672D46
3.#121C31
4.#1E3155
5.#943050

Everything else is pretty much the same.